# Unlocking Osx Local Items keychain

Tags: macos, authentication, authorization, keychain, pam

I'm trying to unlock the Local Items keychain in OSX programmatically.

I'm unlocking login.keychain with /usr/bin/security tool. In some scenarios, unlocking login.keychain programmatically unlocks Local Items indirectly. Other times, Local Items is not unlocked and the user gets several prompts to unlock it. I need to know how to access Local Items directly, in my C program.

Unfortunately, running security list-keychain in /Library/Keychains/ does not even list the Local Items keychain. Why is that?

Is there any way to access and modify Local Items directly?

Platform: Maverick and Yosemite

Update: I have now also tried unlocking the login keychain with the security API (SecKeychainUnlock), the problem with locked Local Items still persists.

Comment: Any leads/help? More background: When I programmatically unlock login.keychain during a session, Local Items also gets unlocked. When I programmatically unlock login.keychain when the user logs into their account, Local Items does not get unlocked and persistently prompts for password. I have rewritten the login process such that it does not rely on a password (I'm providing my own PAM library).

Answer (score 3):

Local Item is not keychain file, it is db file which is named "keychain-2.db". You'll see it in a sub folder in ~/Library/Keychain.

Check this link: https://macmule.com/2014/03/30/the-local-items-keychain-in-mavericks/